# Server-side Flask sessions using Redis on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, redis

I'm deploying a Flask application on Heroku and need to implement server-side sessions for various reasons, and I can't figure out how to properly set it up.
Heroku's [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#connecting-in-python) on how to connect are quite minimalistic:

```
import os
import redis

r = redis.from_url(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
```

I'm trying to get this running with the [Flask-Session extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/#quickstart). According to their quickstart example:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
# Check Configuration section for more details
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/set/')
def set():
    session['key'] = 'value'
    return 'ok'
```

I'm confused as to how the two are connected, as the redis module isn't even imported in the latter example. Reading further on the Flask-session page, there's a table of "*A list of configuration keys also understood by the extension:*", one of which being "SESSION_REDIS", with the description "A redis.Redis instance, default connect to 127.0.0.1:6379". I'm guessing this is the instance (r) from Heroku's docs, but the phrase "keys understood by the extension" gives me no clue regarding what to actually do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flask-session is quite badly documented. *keys understood by the extension* means you can specify listed configuration options, pass them to your flask app and Flask-session would acknowledge and use those options. It's called keys because flask app accepts configuration in a form of a key-value dictionary.

In Flask-session they use quite unusual approach to configure it: instead of passing such options as host, port, etc. as strings, they require you to pass a configured redis client object:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
SESSION_REDIS = Redis(host="your_host", port=1234)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)
```

Comment: Okay, so when I call app.config.from_object(__name__) it automatically looks for the variable names from the left column of the docs (e.g. SESSION_REDIS) and uses them?

Comment: I suppose it looks during the `Session(app)` step. In the `app.config.from_object(name)` step it loads config from the object (`__name__` points to the current python module) and binds values from it to the `app` object.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Not sure if I'm missing something but that's seems like an exceptionally strange and messy way instead of just passing the relevant arguments explicitly. Do you know if there's a good reason for this choice?

Comment: Well, [you can pass relevant arguments explicitly](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/). But in the Flask-session doc they've chosen one the most implicit (but quite convenient) way to setup settings in their example which is not a good choice as it requires a quite good knowledge of how flask configuration works.